# Windows Service stuck on "starting" status as local system account

Tags: c#, windows-services

I developed a http server via console application in C# and decided to turn it into a Windows service to be able to initialize it without the need to login the machine.

I followed all the steps in [How to create Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9k985bc9(v=vs.110).aspx) and chose the account as "Local System", but when I install in my server machine and push the start button it takes a while and gives the following error:

> Erro 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in timely fashion.

After that, the service status stays stuck in "starting" and the application don't work and I can't even stop the service anymore.

Trying to work around this problem, I changed it to "Network Service", so it started normally, but the application was not listening in the port I set when I checked in the prompt with the command "netstat -an". But the application listens normally if i run it as a console application.

So I am looking for an answer to one of these two questions:

1. What should I do to make the service starts properly with a Local System account?
2. If I decide to use Network service account, what should I care about to guarantee that my service works properly as a server?

Comment: OnStart should finish in 30 seconds. Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631364/c-sharp-windows-service

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When I converted my console application to windows service I simply put my code directly in the OnStart method. However, I realized the OnStart method should start the service, but needs to end some time to the service indeed start. So I created a thread that runs my service and let the OnStart method finish. I tested and the service worked just fine. Here is how it was the code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Listener(); // this method never returns
}
```

Here is how it worked:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listener));
    t.Start();
}
```

But I still don't understand why the service ran (passed the "starting" status, but didn't work) when I used network service account. If anyone knows, I'll be glad to know the reason.

Comment: Best guess is that the call to Listener() was silently failing, probably because Network Service lacked a necessary access permission and the error checking wasn't comprehensive enough.

Comment: I did a similar thing with a purposeful infinite loop that doesn't return. I ended up kicking it off with `Task.Run(() => MyMethod());`

Comment: if it was a http server, it is probably waiting for a connection, and never returning, that's why the Listener() never returns and the service is always in "Starting" mode; doing the thread is the right solution

Comment: It's strange! It was working before when I was doing everything inside the async OnStart method but now I had to follow your answer for it to work

Answer (score 21):

If you have a service that is not responding or showing pending in Windows services that you are unable to stop, use the following directions to force the service to stop.

- `Start` -> `Run` or `Start` -> type `services.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Look for the service and check the Properties and identify its service name
- Once found, open a command prompt. Type `sc queryex [servicename]`
- Identify the PID (process ID)
- In the same command prompt type `taskkill /pid [pid number] /f`

Comment: After run `sc queryex ` command,If you get nothong;you should run command in cmd,or execute `cmd` command in powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Find PID of Service

> sc queryex <SERVICE_NAME>

Give result's below

SERVICE_NAME: Foo.Services.Bar TYPE : 10 WIN32_OWN_PROCESS STATE : 2 0 START_PENDING (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN) WIN32_EXIT_CODE : 0 (0x0) SERVICE_EXIT_CODE : 0 (0x0) CHECKPOINT : 0x0 WAIT_HINT : 0x0 PID : 3976 FLAGS :

Now Kill the Service:

> taskkill /f /pid 3976

SUCESS: The process with PID 3976 has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows Application event log, it could contain some entries from your service's auto generated event source (which should have the same name of the service).

Comment: I checked, but I found no log related to my service. I added one more information to my question: when I try to start the service i get the following error: Erro 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in timely fashion. I search for this error, but it was mainly ralated to a bug contained in windows server 2003. My windows server is 2012, so I think the bug fix does not apply to case. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase the windows service timeout with a key in the registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
```

> "ServicesPipeTimeout"=dword:300000   (300 seconds or 5 minutes)

If it doesn't exists it has to be created.

Comment: The value is in milliseconds, so the 300000 you specified means 300 seconds (5 minutes),  not 30 seconds.   (See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/922918/a-service-does-not-start-and-events-7000-and-7011-are-logged-in-window)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a while loop that looked at an external queue. The while-loop continued running until the queue was empty. Solved it by calling a timer event directly only when `Environment.UserInteractive`. Therefore the service could be debugged easily but when running as a service it would wait for the timers `ElapsedEventHandler` event.

Service:

```
partial class IntegrationService : ServiceBase
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private System.Timers.Timer timer;

    public IntegrationService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Add code here to start your service.
            logger.Info($"Starting IntegrationService");

            var updateIntervalString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UpdateInterval"];
            var updateInterval = 60000;
            Int32.TryParse(updateIntervalString, out updateInterval);

            var projectHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectIntegrationServiceHost"];
            var projectIntegrationApiService = new ProjectIntegrationApiService(new Uri(projectHost));
            var projectDbContext = new ProjectDbContext();
            var projectIntegrationService = new ProjectIntegrationService(projectIntegrationApiService, projectDbContext);
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            var integrationProcessor = new IntegrationProcessor(updateInterval, projectIntegrationService, timer);
            timer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Fatal(e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            // Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
            timer.Enabled = false;
            timer.Dispose();
            timer = null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Fatal(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Processor:

```
public class IntegrationProcessor
{
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private static volatile bool _workerIsRunning;
    private int _updateInterval;
    private ProjectIntegrationService _projectIntegrationService;

    public IntegrationProcessor(int updateInterval, ProjectIntegrationService projectIntegrationService, Timer timer)
    {
        _updateInterval = updateInterval;
        _projectIntegrationService = projectIntegrationService;

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        timer.Interval = _updateInterval;

        //Don't wait for first elapsed time - Should not be used when running as a service due to that Starting will hang up until the queue is empty
        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            OnTimedEvent(null, null);
        }
        _workerIsRunning = false;
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_workerIsRunning == false)
            {
                _workerIsRunning = true;

                ProjectInformationToGet infoToGet = null;
                _logger.Info($"Started looking for information to get");
                //Run until queue is empty
                while ((infoToGet = _projectIntegrationService.GetInformationToGet()) != null)
                {
                    //Set debugger on logger below to control how many cycles the service should run while debugging.
                    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    _logger.Info($"Started Stopwatch");
                    _logger.Info($"Found new information, updating values");
                    _projectIntegrationService.AddOrUpdateNewInformation(infoToGet);
                    _logger.Info($"Completed updating values");
                    watch.Stop();
                    _logger.Info($"Stopwatch stopped. Elapsed seconds: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000}. " +
                                 $"Name queue items: {infoToGet.NameQueueItems.Count} " +
                                 $"Case queue items: {infoToGet.CaseQueueItems.Count} " +
                                 $"Fee calculation queue items: {infoToGet.FeeCalculationQueueItems.Count} " +
                                 $"Updated foreign keys: {infoToGet.ShouldUpdateKeys}");
                }

                _logger.Info($"Nothing more to get from integration service right now");

                _workerIsRunning = false;
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.Info($"Worker is already running! Will check back again after {_updateInterval / 1000} seconds");
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException exception)
        {
            var newException = new FormattedDbEntityValidationException(exception);
            HandelException(newException);
            throw newException;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            HandelException(exception);
            //If an exception occurs when running as a service, the service will restart and run again
            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandelException(Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.Fatal(exception);
        _workerIsRunning = false;
    }
}
```