# Explain why "using" won't work in service?

Tags: c#, signalr, using

So I was stuck on this problem for about a week. I was trying to run a project to recieve a TCP connection and start a SignalR Hub as a Service. Both worked perfectly running the project as a **.exe** file. The TCP part would work perfectly, however I was having problems with the SignalR side.

The reason ended up being the **using** statement.

**Before**

```
using (WebApp.Start<SignalrStartup>(url))
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url); // was url
    Console.WriteLine("ID\tMessage");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**After**

```
WebApp.Start<SignalrStartup>(url);
```

I had tried running the the code with the `Console.WriteLine()` commented out, as I thought it might be throwing an exception as the is no console to output to once run as a service. This also didn't work, but also wouldn't work as a **.exe** file either as it needed the `Console.ReadLine()` to keep the console open, sort of how you need it to keep **HelloWorld.cs** open. Once the **using** wrapper was removed along with the **console**, it would then work in both the **.exe** and the service.

I have read that the **using** statement kills objects in it once you leave the wrapper. But I don't understand how the **After** bit of code keeps the **.exe** code open once running. Is there any point in using **using** or have I been using it wrong?

**Edit**

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => StartTCP())
        .ContinueWith(t => StartSignalR());
}
```

The call is being made from the `StartSignalR()` method.

Comment: In which section of the service are you creating this? In a service, you cannot block the start method like you would in a console app. If ReadLine  doesn't block, then dispose will be called. Save the IDisposable as a member and dispose it in the Stop method

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### What's Going Wrong With Your Service?

The problem you're having is that your `Console.ReadLine` does a blocking wait for standard input. That will block forever on a windows service and cause the service control manager to time out the service start after 30 seconds. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2631364/1353098) has more information about what's going on.

If you remove the entire contents of the using statement, and the statement itself as you have done the server that was started by `WebApp.Start` will continue on in the background after your service `Start` method completes. This is the correct behaviour of a service.

What you're effectively doing here is to leak the asynchronous workers that `WebApp.Start` created. This means that they're still running after the service start completes to listen for requests.

You should probably keep track of the `IDisposable` that `WebApp.Start` returns though, and dispose it in the `Stop` method.

### What About `using`?

A [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) makes sure a resource is always disposed when control leaves the `using` statement's block. This can be either due to an exception being thrown or because the block completes successfully and control moves on to the next part of the program.

`using` statements are used when you know that nothing wants to access the resource after the block has completed. This is usually the case when you're dealing with methods that return an `IDisposable` to you. In your case however you don't want to call dispose because you want the threads that `WebApp.Start` created to continue after the service has started.

Answer (score 8):

Webapp.Start<> starts worker threads. These threads keeps your exe running, even after the code in your HelloWorld.cs has finished executing. Your exe will not shut down until all worker threads have been stopped.

When you add your "using"-statement, the framework will call Dispose on your SignalR application. This call will stop all the work threads, and your exe will terminate.

The Readline() statement stops the app from reaching the end of the using statement. This means the dispose method is not called until you press enter.

So, for an exe you normally want to use ReadLine the way you do.
For a service you want to store a reference to your IDisposable, and call dispose on it in you Stop() method.